# Bootstrap 3 - Space between inputs with Icons and custom width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input, icons, adminlte

I'm facing a problem I don't really know how to deal with.
I'm working on BootStrap 3 and i'm trying to make some inline forms because it is more user-friendly than a full vertical form (I don't want to scroll for ever)

I find some way to inline the normal inputs, but when it comes to the input with icons (`font awesome`), I can figure how to inline them, but they inline side to side without any space between them. 
Also, I don't figure out how to change their width as I would do with normal input (`col-sm-4` for example).

I would like the "Email" and "Telephone" to be scaped and to change their width

Please have a look at my code and the following image explaining it: 
http://www.bootply.com/T8w3oRE3Sn

[image]

Comment: what is the output you need? can you share a image of that?

Comment: @SahilDhir I added an image to show the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You were missing few things in the form group so I have wrapped things up.** `Hope it will help you :)`

> Below is the working snippet:

```css
.myform .form-inline .input-group .input-group-addon{ width:20px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row myform">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <form name="myform" role="form" novalidate>

      <div class="form-inline ">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
          <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email de l'interlocuteur">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
          <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Téléphone de l'interlocuteur">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Sahil, I will have a look at this but apparently that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Yes please have a look and tell me if you need any help in this

Comment: I have at least one question, if you don't mind. Why using `col-xs`instead of `col-sm`. I've tried with `col-sm`but it doesn't work and the space disapear

Comment: col-xs will make it repsonsive for all device widths... Also i am updating my answer for all device compatibilties

Comment: Understood. And is there any way to make the space bigger/smaller ?

Comment: Updated my answer with a small custom css needed . Now its compatible for all devices(desktop, laptop, tablet, mobiles)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> IF you see it in large screen it will be inline.
>   You have to use `form-inline` class to make form inline.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You just need to deal with good understanding of bootstrap grid system

```
<div class="form-group row">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Interlocuteur</label>

              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3">
              </div>

              <label for="inputEmail5" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Poste</label>

              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail5" placeholder="DeInterlocuteur">
              </div>
```

Comment: Tejas I was actually asking for the two inputs "Email" and "Telephone"